# function calling a service only works when initializing

Tags: angularjs

Getting started with AngularJS working through the W3schools tutorial.

I'm trying to expand on some of the sample code by creating an input which is used by the function getHex(), which uses the service hexafy.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <p>The hexadecimal value of <input ng-model="inputNo"/> is:</p>    
    <h1>{{getHex()}}</h1>   
</div>

<p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.inputNo = 255;
    $scope.getHex = function() {
        return hexafy.myFunc($scope.inputNo);   
    };
});
</script>
```

When the page firsts load, the input contains 255 and the {{getHex()}} is rendered as ff, so the function appears to run correctly.

But when I change the value in the input, it just returns exactly my input into {{getHex()}} without hexify-ing it. getHex() is supposed to return the result of hexafy.myFunc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the `$scope.inputNo` to int before sending to the service

```
return hexafy.myFunc(parseInt($scope.inputNo));
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/iM5KeKuArj1RbEHX0rQ5?p=preview)

Comment: This seems functionally equivalent to my sample code. Mine is also updating the html {{getHex()}}, but I am not getting the expected value. For example, when initially run on page load, 255 is returned as ff. But when I change the value to 254, it returns 254. If I type in 255, it returns 255. It only returns the Hex value of the input when the page first loads.

Comment: Any idea why it was correctly rendering ff on the initial load then?

Comment: because initially its an integer. but when you are changing it in the input its convert to a string type

Answer (score 1):

Convert the sent payload to a javascript `Number` before converting to hex.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('hexafy', function() {
  var hexafyService = {};

  var _myFunc = function(x) {
    return Number(x).toString(16);
  }

  hexafyService.myFunc = _myFunc;
  return hexafyService;
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.inputNo = 200;
  $scope.getHex = function() {
    $scope.hexNo = hexafy.myFunc($scope.inputNo);
  };
  $scope.getHex();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>The hexadecimal value of <input ng-model="inputNo" ng-change="getHex()" /> is:</p>
  <h1>{{hexNo}}</h1>
</div>

<p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>
```